# Could you advise to discover any bluetooth device on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I try to make program to detect uncertain Bluetooth device at iOS.

The device scanning work well but it could not detect any device. However in the basic option in Ipad, the bluetooth devices were detected well. Bellow show the my code. Please advise to fix some problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //CB setup
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    // You should test all scenarios
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        _scan_state = 1;
    }

    [self deviceScan];

}
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI{
    NSLog(@"dicovered: %@", peripheral.name);

    if(![self.BTNames containsObject:peripheral]){
        [self.BTNames addObject:peripheral];
    }


    _num_cell = self.BTNames.count;

    [self.BTList reloadData];

}

- (void) deviceScan{
    if(_scan_state){
/*        [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @NO }];*/
        [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        NSLog(@"Scan Starting");
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of device is it?  CoreBluetooth can only discover Bluetooth Low Energy/BT 4.0 devices. The system settings can display legacy Bluetooth devices such as headsets, which will not be reported by Core Bluetooth

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.
Are there any ways to detect lower bluetooth version devices?

Comment: No.  Bluetooth devices such as headsets & A2DP can be accessed through the AV framework but the user must complete pairing through settings.  Other device types (such as SPP profile devices) must go through the MFi program

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. Actually, I use the android smart phone as the target device which has the bluetooth 4.0 module. Of course, it was permitted to the searching mode on my phone. However, it also was not discovered. Could you check my code on above? Are there any mistake?

Comment: It looks ok at first glance. I suggest using the free Light Blue app from the App Store to try and detect your android device as a validation that it is advertising a service

Comment: I'm really appreciated your kind answer. I solve this problem buying the new BLE module.